# Accessing object representing Angular component in the DOM

Tags: angular

Is there a way to access object representing Angular component in the DOM through some kind of reference and invoke methods on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

html

```
<component></component>
<div *ngIf="componentObj"> componentObj.Method() </div>
```

typescript

```
    @ViewChild(component)
    public componentObj: ComponentType;
```

Comment: Yes, this is one way, but actually I was looking for a way to communicate and hence allow for method invocation between arbitrary components in an Angular interface and realised that probably only service will all for that. So now I inject a common service to components that need to speak to each other.